# CASE statement not working well

Tags: mysql

Hey guys i am new to mysql actually..I have wrote a code something like

```
 CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2), 
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);


INSERT INTO  CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)  
VALUES (1,'aff',2,3,5);
```

My case statement look like

```
 select CASE WHEN ID > 0 THEN SET NAME  = 'SDFSDF'; ELSE SET NAME = 'ASD'
END CASE;
from CUSTOMERS
```

When i run this on sql fiddle it gives me error like

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET NAME = 'SDFSDF'; ELSE SET NAME = 'ASD' END CASE' at line 1: select CASE WHEN ID > 0 THEN SET NAME = 'SDFSDF'; ELSE SET NAME = 'ASD' END CASE`

Can anyone help me ..any help would be appreciatd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct statement is

```
select 
case 
 when id > 0 then 'sdfsdf' 
 else 'asd' end as name 
from customers ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is wrong. The structure of your query should be like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ID > 0 
                THEN 'SDFSDF' 
                ELSE 'ASD'
           END AS NAME
    FROM CUSTOMERS
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to update the values in the table?

In that case, use this:

```
UPDATE customers SET name = CASE WHEN ID > 0 THEN 'SDFSDF' ELSE 'ASD' END
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do what the error message suggests? [Read about the right syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html).
You should notice that there are `;` in your statement which don't belong there.

Correct statement should read:

```
select CASE WHEN ID > 0 
           THEN 'SDFSDF'
           ELSE 'ASD'
       END CASE as Name
from CUSTOMERS;
```

Note that there aren't any `;` after `THEN` or `END`. Also, the `SET` doesn't belong there either.

Comment: This is still invalid. The `SET` keyword does not belong inside a `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
select CASE WHEN ID > 0 THEN SET NAME  = 'SDFSDF' ELSE SET NAME = 'ASD'
END CASE as customer_name from CUSTOMERS
```

Answer (score 0):

Guy,
your question is bad. You didn't do any efforts. Just look into the syntax of [CASE control function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)

You should remove CASE word from the end.

```
Select CASE WHEN ID > 0 THEN SET NAME  = 'SDFSDF'; ELSE SET NAME = 'ASD'
END /* CASE */;
/*from CUSTOMERS*/
```

answer:

```
select *, (Select CASE WHEN ID > 0 THEN SET NAME  = 'SDFSDF'
          ELSE SET NAME = 'ASD' END)
from CUSTOMERS
```